# Can't manage subscription in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-server

I'm working with free trial and I don't noticed that it finished, I have a lot of valuable work on it, how to change it to my credit card? I add it when I started.

I can't get into my subscription.

The same problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ae8bd821-76b4-4e9c-aa76-de614df3e499/subscription-page-we-are-sorry-but-we-could-not-complete-that-operation?forum=windowsazurepurchasing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens! Don't worry...it's a job for Azure Tech Support.
You can use the "can't log into my account" page or the free "billing" support line to tell them you want to add a credit card. Both options are here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/